# Extension to extract column from DataRow[] as List, Array, etc with same data type

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, extension-methods, system.data

I want to make an extension method for System.Data.DataRow[] that will take a single column from the DataRow[] and convert it to a list, array, etc *of the columns data type*.

Originally I had this as a string extension that would churn out an array of strings, but wanted to explore a more general solution for different data types.

The string solution was as follows..

```
 public static string[] ExtractColumn(this DataRow[] DataRows, string Column)
    {
        if (DataRows.Count() == 0) { return null; }

        string[] returnString = new string[DataRows.Count()];

        int i = 0;

        foreach (DataRow r in DataRows ?? new DataRow[0])
        {
            returnString[i] = r[Column].ToString();

            i++;
        }
        return returnString;
    }
```

When I started working out a more general approach I got stuck on building a List of T where T is the type of the DataColumn.

```
    public static List<T> ColumnToArray<T>(this DataRow[] DataRows, string Column)
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        if (DataRows.Count() == 0) { return null; }

        foreach (DataRow r in DataRows ?? new DataRow[0])
        {
            list.Add(r[Column]); //<-- Does not compile
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I tried to make a local list like so:
     `List<DataRows[0][Column].GetType()> list = new List<DataRows[0][Column].GetType()>();`
but this does not compile.

So my question(s) are:

1. Is it possible to do what I am trying with generics?
2. Is there an alternative / pre existing exension method for accomplishing this?
3. What would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the value to the type of the list:

```
list.Add((T)r[Column]);
```

Alternatively use the `Field` extension method:

```
list.Add(r.Field<T>(Column));
```

You might also want to handle null values, for example:

```
list.Add(r.IsNull(Column) ? default(T) : r.Field<T>(Column));
```

Note: `default(int)` for example is `0`, so you might want to specify what to use for null values as a parameter, or add an overload of the method for value types that returns a `List<T?>` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to DataSet row [`Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) extension and simplify your code to

```
public static List<T> ColumnToArray<T>(this DataRow[] rows, string columnName)
{
    // check if rows not null
    return rows.Select(r => r.Field<T>(columnName)).ToList();
}
```

NOTE: I would throw `ArgumentNullException` when `rows` argument is null. Consider also to use `IEnumerable<DataRow>` instead of array.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this answer and that it is based on an existing extension method. In this scenario I would ideally mark both as an answer, as my final solution will be a combination of the two.  However I am marking Guffa's response as the answer due to the additional handling of non nullable types.